# NewtonSoft JArray - how to select multiple elements with LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, json.net

I have some JSON which I then parse to JArray object. I want to filter the JArray so it then has only two properties, Title and BodyText. But whatever I try I can only select one value using LINQ.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult AjaxGetNewsItems()
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(news.GetNewsItems(), formatting:Formatting.Indented);
    var v = JArray.Parse(json);

    //var items =
    //    v.Where(
    //        x =>
    //            x["Title"].ToString() != string.Empty &&
    //            x["BodyText"].ToString() != string.Empty)
    //        .Select(x => x["Title"])
    //        .ToList();

    var title = (string) v[0]["Title"];

    var titleBodytext = from p in v
    select v[0]["Title"]["BodyText"];
    foreach (var item in titleBodytext)
    {
    }
    //var titleBodytext =
    //    from c in v[0]["Title"]["BodyText"]
    //    group c by c
    //    into g
    //    select new {  };

    //JArray a = JArray.FromObject(news.GetNewsItems());
    //string titleBodytext = (string) newsItems["Title"]["Bodytext"];

    return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = json,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
    };
}
```

I want to change this code:

```
var titleBodytext = from p in v
                    select v[0]["Title"]["BodyText"];
```

`Title` and `BodyText` are two keys values in my JArray.

[image]

See screenshot of JArray object. In element 0 there are key value elements.

Comment: Try this `var titleBodytext=from p in v select new { Title=p[0]["title"],Body=p[0]["bodyText"]`

Comment: @Thirisangu I'll try that now. So I want to project it into annoymous collection?

Comment: @Thirisangu I have this error: Additional information: Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.

Comment: Try this : `Title=p.Title,Body=p.BodyText`

Comment: @Thirisangu That won't work because it needs [key]. I have been able to select values with v[0]["Title"]. I don't understand why selecting multiple values is this confusing.

Comment: It will : `var result=from p in v select p;foreach(var lp in p){var title=lp[0]["title"];var body=lp[0]["body"];}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way :

```
var titleBodytext = from p in v
                    select new 
                           {
                             Title = (string)p["Title"],
                             Text = (string)p["BodyText"]
                           };
```

Or if you're sure `v` always contain only one element :

```
var titleBodytext = new 
                    { 
                        Title = (string)v[0]["Title"], 
                        Text = (string)v[0]["BodyText"] 
                    };
```

BTW, your current code doesn't seems to do what you think. It has `p in v` in the `from` clause, but always select `v[0]` regardless of current `p` being the context. Anyway, this doesn't show wrong behavior in the case where `v` only contain one element.

Comment: Thanks your code works. I'm not quite sure what I was doing wrong. I didn't need the index maybe? I've used LINQ often and it's never been this troublesome.

Comment: @nickgowdy yes, you didn't need the index and more importantly you need to operate on `p` instead of `v` in the `select` clause..

Comment: @hara07 Ok I see why it wasn't working. Thanks for your help.