# Newtonsoft JArray - Select Multiple Values from Array specificed by node

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, json.net

I want to select the value `servicePlanName` and `provisioningStatus` by the `skuPartNumber`

For example, if I specified `"skuPartNumber": "POWER_BI_STANDARD"` I should get the following

```
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION
PendingProvisioning

BI_AZURE_P0
Success
```

I have referred to the Newtonsoft docs [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) and [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonLinq.htm#!)
and on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423398/newtonsoft-jarray-how-to-select-multiple-elements-with-linq)

This is the JSON

```
{
    "@odata.context": "",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "00-00-0",
            "skuId": "0-000-0000-00-00000",
            "skuPartNumber": "POWER_BI_STANDARD",
            "servicePlans": [
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION",
                    "provisioningStatus": "PendingProvisioning",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "BI_AZURE_P0",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "000-0000",
            "skuId": "0-000-00-00-000",
            "skuPartNumber": "STANDARDPACK",
            "servicePlans": [
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "DYN365_CDS_O365_P1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "KAIZALA_O365_P2",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "MICROSOFT_SEARCH",
                    "provisioningStatus": "PendingProvisioning",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "WHITEBOARD_PLAN1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "MYANALYTICS_P2",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "OFFICEMOBILE_SUBSCRIPTION",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "BPOS_S_TODO_1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "FORMS_PLAN_E1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "STREAM_O365_E1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "Deskless",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "FLOW_O365_P1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "POWERAPPS_O365_P1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "TEAMS1",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTWAC",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "SWAY",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "INTUNE_O365",
                    "provisioningStatus": "PendingActivation",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "YAMMER_ENTERPRISE",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "MCOSTANDARD",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTSTANDARD",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Disabled",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "000000000000000-0000000-000",
            "skuId": "00000000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
            "skuPartNumber": "PROJECTPREMIUM",
            "servicePlans": [
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "PROJECT_PROFESSIONAL",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "FLOW_FOR_PROJECT",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "DYN365_CDS_PROJECT",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION",
                    "provisioningStatus": "PendingProvisioning",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTWAC",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINT_PROJECT",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                },
                {
                    "servicePlanId": "0000000-0000000-00000-0000-0000000",
                    "servicePlanName": "PROJECT_CLIENT_SUBSCRIPTION",
                    "provisioningStatus": "Success",
                    "appliesTo": "Company"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried the following

```
   public static async Task<string[]> GetUserApplicationSubscriptionsForSpecificLicence(HttpClient client, string user)
        {
            var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/licenseDetails");
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(payload);
   
            var groupDescription = from g in obj["value"].Children()
                                   where g["skuPartNumber"].Contains("STANDARDPACK")
                                   select g["servicePlans"].Children().Value<string>();

            return groupDescription.ToArray();
        }
```

```
public static async Task<string[]> GetUserApplicationSubscriptionsForSpecificLicence2(HttpClient client, string user)
        {
            var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/licenseDetails");
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(payload);
    
            IList<string> storeNames = obj.SelectToken("$..value[?(@.skuPartNumber== 'PROJECTPREMIUM')]").Select(s => (string)s).ToList();
     
            return storeNames.ToArray();
        }
```

I cannot get my head around it.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ you can do something like this:

```
var result = obj["value"]
        .Children()
        .Where(c => c["skuPartNumber"].Value<string>() == "POWER_BI_STANDARD")
        .Select(c => c["servicePlans"])
        .Where(i => i != null)
        .SelectMany(i => i.Children())
        .Select(c => (planName: c["servicePlanName"], status: c["provisioningStatus"]))
        .ToList();
```

This will return for your json collection of 2 tuples:

```
planName                status  
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION   PendingProvisioning 
BI_AZURE_P0             Success
```

Or if you want just strings you can do:

```
var strings = obj["value"]
        .Children()
        .Where(c => c["skuPartNumber"].Value<string>() == "POWER_BI_STANDARD")
        .Select(c => c["servicePlans"])
        .Where(i => i != null)
        .SelectMany(i => i.Children())
        .SelectMany(c => new[] { c["servicePlanName"].Value<string>(), c["provisioningStatus"].Value<string>()})
        .ToArray();
```

Using json path:

```
    var strings = obj.SelectTokens("$.value[?(@.skuPartNumber == 'POWER_BI_STANDARD')].servicePlans[*].['servicePlanName','provisioningStatus']")
        .Select(t => t.Value<string>())
        .ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the variety of answers ! This is perfect